# Legality of hanging things outside your window?

Tags: windows, building-regulations

I have been thinking of hanging something outside my window. It occurred to me though that there are building codes. I am in a private home of my own but wondered to what extent building codes apply.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Building codes don't apply to you or your behavior after construction. Are you asking about neighborhood association rules or city statutes?

Comment: If you could be more specific about what you're hanging, that would help us with forming an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with building codes, unless you are hanging an addition to your house out the window.

Your own (single-family) home on your own lot (piece of land) - depends what you have (or don't) for a home-owner's association, or if your house is subject to some sort of restrictive covenant such as a historic preservation district.

A home that is part of a multiple-dwelling unit where you own the space in the building, but not the land - more likely to have some other rules and regulations impacting what you can do from your windows, in the interest of protecting other people.

Note that on your own property you still have an interest in protecting other people, but it comes mostly from the fact that they can sue you, so if you plan to hang something very dubious safety-wise out the window, your insurance company may decide that you are a bad risk and cancel your coverage or raise your rates.

Comment: Thanks. I know various Dishes etc. are hung outside peoples windows. What happens if one of these falls on someones head? Does the dish company get sued or the person (if a private single residence)?

Comment: The homeowner will get sued. If you are lucky, the installer was insured an you (or your insurance company) can sue them to recover some of those funds. Your property, your responsibility to make sure it's done right.